# I broke this lua script

Tags: lua

This is the Error Code below.

```
[ERROR] gamemodes/dayz/gamemode/init.lua:64: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value
  1. unknown - gamemodes/dayz/gamemode/init.lua:64
```

and here is the init.lua script.

```
62  function GM:PlayerDeath(victim, inflictor, attacker)

63    if (IsValid(attacker) and attacker:IsPlayer()) then

64        attacker:SetNWInt("playerMoney", attacker:SetNWInt("playerMoney")+50)

65        attacker:SetNWInt("playerExp", attacker:SetNWInt("playerExp")+ 100)

66        attacker:SetFrags(attacker:Frags() + 1)

67  

68        checkForLevel(attacker)

69    end

70  end
```

please help me with feedback on how I messed this up.

Comment: Maybe some `SetNWInt` should be `GetNWInt` instead?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff good guess, the same probably goes for `"playerExp"`.

Answer (score 0):

function GM:PlayerDeath(victim, inflictor, attacker) if IsValid(attacker) and attacker:IsPlayer() then attacker:SetNWInt("playerMoney", attacker:GetNWInt("playerMoney") + 50) attacker:SetNWInt("playerExp", attacker:GetNWInt("playerExp") + 100) attacker:SetFrags(attacker:Frags() + 1)

```
checkForLevel(attacker)
```

end